# Regex - Select content by `contains` condition?

Tags: javascript, regex

Looking at this string :

```
[app/default-viewcomponent.ts]
```

I need to select the whole string only if it contains `.` (at least one)

This is what I've managed to do and it works (partially):

```
(\[(.(?=.*\.[^\]]+)).*\])
```

- ()  - becuase I need to  extract the group content
- `(.(?=.*\.[^\]]+))` positive lookahead - get all chars which has a future dot
- `.*\]` - after the dot there can be more content which is closed with `]`.

Looking at this image , there is a match :

[image]

But if I move the dot to last char before `]` , there's no match :

[image: [app/default-viewcomponentts.]]

**Question:**

I think I know what the problem is , it's becuase the regex don't match a situation where the dot is right before the `]`.

How can I fix my regex , Also - is there's a better/simpler way of doing it ?

[**REGEX101**](https://regex101.com/r/WLm8yQ/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the `+` in there causing the problem, because burried in your regex is the condition

> Any character that is NOT in this class: []], one or more repetitions

Changing that `+` to a `*` (any number of repetitions) fixes the problem.

New regex: `(\[(.(?=.*\.[^\]]*)).*\])`

Tested against

```
[app/default-viewcomponentts.]  
[app/default-viewcomponent.ts]  
[app/default-viewcomponent.ts.]
```

Comment: Need also to add  `$` in `(\[(.(?=.*\.[^\]]*)).*\]$)` for `[app/default-viewcomponentts].` ( dot at the end)

Answer (score 3):

You can solve the problem with no lookarounds, use 2 negated character classes:

```
\[[^\].]*\.[^\]]*\]
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ysogoq/1)

Note that this way you only match `[...]` if the dot is *inside* the brackets. Your original regex matches `[...]` if a dot is after the closing bracket, too, due to the `.` pattern used in the lookahead and `.` matches *any* char but a line break char.

**Details**

- `\[` - a literal `[`
- `[^\].]*` - zero or more chars other than `]` and `.`
- `\.` - a dot
- `[^\]]*` -  zero or more chars other than `]`
- `\]` - a literal `]` (need no escaping, but just escaped for consistency).

Answer (score 0):

You could check if the string contains a dot with the regex `/^[[].*[.].*[]]$/g` that match strings:

- `^[[]` starts with a `[`
- `.*` contains any chars
- `[.]` contains at least a dot
- `.*` contains any chars
- `[]]$` ends with a `]`

```js
var regex = /^[\[].*[.].*[\]]$/g;

function check(par){
  console.log(par + " match: " + regex.test(par));
}

check("[app/default-viewcomponent.ts]");
check("[app/default-viewcomponentts.]");
check("[app/default-viewcomponentts]");
```

```html
Test other string <input type="text" id="test" value="" onchange="javascript:check(this.value)">
```

Note: with javascript I've to escape the brackets.